# Replace object with existing value in array in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have an ng-repeat with a select in every item.

The user can select a value (trigging a function that pushes the an object into an array), but they can also change their mind, in which case the code just pushes a second object with the new value, duplicating the first one.

How could I manage to actually delete existing values, leaving only the last one on every ng-change?

Here's my HTML:

```
<select ng-change="insertproduct(pa.nom, basket)" ng-model="basket">
  <option ng-repeat="select in numberofproducts">{{select}}</option>
</select>
```

And my javascript:

```
$scope.numberofproducts = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

$scope.singleorder = [];

$scope.insertproduct = function(nom, basket){
  $scope.numero = {
    'producte': nom,
    'numero': basket
  };
  $scope.singleorder.push($scope.numero);
  console.log($scope.singleorder);
}
```

The idea is to create a condition in which if the array contains an object with the parameter ´producte´ equal to the new one, delete the existing and push the new one.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

First, use the [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) method to check if an object with the same property is already in the `singleorder` array.

```
function duplicateOrder(order) { 
    return order.producte === nom;
}
var index = $scope.singleorder.findIndex(duplicateOrder);
```

*Note: [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#Browser_compatibility) for findIndex is limited; it is not supported in Internet Explorer.*

Then remove the item with [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
if(index > -1){
$scope.singleorder.splice(index, 1);
}
```

You can then push the new one in.

---

You should also clean up your coding style: **don't mix french and english**, and use either **camelCase** or **snake_case** for your functions to improve readability.

Answer (score 0):

**Observation :**

- Use AngularJS [**ngOptions**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) attribute instead of `ng-repeat`.
- You can check the `index` of the element in an array if that was already there you can easily remove previous one.

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.numberofproducts = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

    $scope.newArray = [];

    $scope.insertproduct = function(basket) {
      var prevIndex = $scope.newArray.indexOf(basket);
      if(prevIndex > -1) {
        $scope.newArray.splice(prevIndex, 1);
      } else {
        $scope.newArray.push(basket);
      }
      console.log($scope.newArray);
    }
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <select ng-change="insertproduct(basket)" ng-model="basket" ng-options="select for select in numberofproducts">
</select>
</div>
```